# I need to cut unwanted txt from string in my DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I need to cut unwanted txt from one string in my DataFrame.

df looks like this:

```
                                A        B      C
0                             526      204  40.88 
1                             177      173  59.25
2                             196      228  47.24
3  1.0 1393 Name: KP, dtype: int64     155  52.83
```

In 3 raw column A i need to leave only 1393, everything else need to be cut/deleted.

This is code of function that make dictiorany. This dictionary i append as last row to df.

```
    final_list = {}
    
    for i in list_of_column:
        temp_list = []

        if i == 'KP':
            temp_series = df3['KP'].where(df3['KP'] == 1).dropna().value_counts()
            temp_list.append(temp_series)

        else:
            if i == "KY1":
                temp_list.append(round(hybryd_mean(i,df1),0))
            elif i != "Wiek":
                temp_list.append(round(hybryd_mean(i,df1),2))
            else:
                temp_list.append(hybryd_mean(i,df1))
        final_list[i] = temp_list
    return final_list
```

and here is hybrid_mean function used in hybrid_dic:

```
    rslt_df = df1[name_of_column].mean()
    
    return rslt_df
```

Comment: You should rather provide the code that you used to generate this dataframe, the error is upstream. It will be easier/cleaner to fix there.

Comment: You can postprocess the dataframe and get your result. But what you apply for this particular case might not work in another case. It would be better to see where the dataframe got the data and why this particular row was parsed wrong. To solve that particular one just split the string using space as separator and take the second element. `myString.split(" ")[1]`. But again, it would be much better go go to the source of the data and correct it there if needed.

Comment: This output is typical of the Series representation, my guess, a bad conversion to string was used

Answer (score 0):

Assuming dtype for this column is str:

```py
df.A = df.A.apply(lambda x: x if len(x) <= 4 else x.split(' ')[1])
```

Comment: This is really not a good way to solve it… both because the problem should **really** be fixed upstream, and because this method is not efficient.

Comment: I agree with you on the fact that the problem is coming from somewhere upstream and should be fixed there but that's not what OP asked for

Comment: What would be a more efficient way of achieving the same? Selecting faulty fields only and modifying only those? Something like `df.A[len(df.A.str) > 4]`? What's your angle on that?

Comment: Why the assumption that len > 4? what if a number has more than 4 digits? ;)

Comment: It's an assumption based on the data that was provided by the OP. My other assumption is that OP is intelligent enough to adjust this value based on any sort of real data he might have